# Python-Removing specific elements from deltatime array

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a deltatime array `dt=[(20,6)(20,7)(20,9)(20,10)(20,11)(20,13)]` and the issue i have is that i cant allow any data to be more than one second apart from the next value in the list. I wrote out a little if statement that goes

```
for k in range(len(dt)-15):
     if dt[k+1].seconds-dt[k].seconds>1:
                 gj.append(dt[k])
                 gj.append(dt[k+1])
```

and I end up with `(20,7)(20,9)(20,11)(20,13)` so I know which times are greater than one second apart, but I can't figure out how to delete the values from a deltatime array. I tried numpy.delete but that didnt work because it's in a non useable format. The end goal is having a new array `[(20,6)(20,10)]` with only data that is one second apart.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check for a difference smaller than 1 second and append those to a list?

## Code

```
from datetime import time

dt = [(20,6), (20,7), (20,9), (20,10), (20,11), (20,13)]
dt = [time(0, m, s) for m, s in dt]

left = []
for i in  range(len(dt) - 1):
    if dt[i + 1].second - dt[i].second <= 1:
        left.append(dt[i])

print(left)
```

## Result

```
>>> [datetime.time(0, 20, 6), datetime.time(0, 20, 9), datetime.time(0, 20, 10)]
```